# Updating a listbox binded list in a cross-thread in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, backgroundworker, multithreading

My question if kind of a two parter. First of all, i have a list of student id's that is constantly added to and removed from within the program. How can i have it so that only the current items in the list are displayed in the listbox. So for example, if i have three id's and i add one, the listbox shows 4 automatically and similarly if i take one item away from the list, the listbox shrinks by 1 entry automatically.

Secondly, all this adding and subtracting to the student id list is done with a backgroundworker_do work thread. So how can i get the above functionality while working outside the ui thread and being in the worker thread? Sample code will be much appreciated

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, you can use an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) instead of a `List`. For the second part, as you know, you cannot update UI elements from backgroundworker thread so you need to marshall the updating logic back to UI thread. This can be achieved by using [`Control.Invoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) / [`Control.BeginInvoke()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx). There are plenty of examples out there for both topics so I'll just let you figure the details out.

EDIT:

For winforms, you can look into [`BindingList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx). Here's a quick example I created.

say you have

```
    class Car
    {
        public string CarName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return CarName;
        }
    }
```

you can create a `BindingList` like this

```
    BindingList<Car> carList = new BindingList<Car>();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        carList.Add(new Car{CarName = "Foo"});
        listBox1.DataSource = carList;
    }
```

add one item to the list and set it as the datasource for the listbox.

Updating the list from the UI thread is simple (note adding to the list automatically adds the item to listbox.

```
    private void btnUIThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        carList.Add(new Car{CarName = "BarFromUIThread"});
    }
```

Here's how you can add (or remove) items from a background worker.

```
private void btnBackgroundworker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
    bg.DoWork += bg_DoWork;
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private delegate void UpdateUIDelegate();
void bg_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Invoke(new UpdateUIDelegate(UpdateListBox));
}

private void UpdateListBox()
{
    carList.Add(new Car { CarName = "BarFromBackgroundWorkerThread" });
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use the observablecollection?

Comment: i cannot find clear example of how the invoke and delagates work. If you know any newbie friendly resource, can you please recommend one?

Comment: @Greg, are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: im using winforms.. I just dont understand the marshalling and the invoking stuff clearly and the msdn is not helping at all

Comment: @Bala R, Hey this is what i understand so far. You can create a delegate and add to it a method that updates the listbox. Using invoke, you can run that delegate outside of the worker thread. THe thing i dont get is the syntax. This is an example i found:  

this.listBox1.Invoke(new AddListBoxItemDelegate(this.AddListBoxItem), item);

Now where in the above does it show the listbox actually adding data to it? I mean like listbox1.Items.Add() What does Invoke actually do about the delagate?

Comment: @Bala R. First of all, thanks a lot for clearing up a lot of doubts. So everytime i want to add to the binding list, i have to call the UpdateListBOx method?

Comment: @Greg when you add an item to the `BindingList` it gets added to the listbox (as it's the listbox's datasource).  `UpdateListBox()` is just an example delegate to demonstrate `Invoke()` call.

Comment: Right i understand that the datasource of the listbox is set to the binding list. But in order to update the listbox(through adding items to the binding list) the add command to the list has to be done on the main ui thread through the invoke call through the UpdateListBox() method correct?

Comment: @Bala R, quick q, how would i accommodate a parameter in the following statement in your example? listBox1.Invoke(new UpdateUIDelegate(UpdateListBox));

Comment: @Greg that would involve updating the `delegate` adding the parameter `private delegate void UpdateUIDelegate(string str);` and  passing the parameter to `Invoke()` like this `listBox1.Invoke(new UpdateUIDelegate(UpdateListBox),new[]{"SomeNewName"});`

Answer (score 0):

i don't completely understand the first part, what do you mean with current items?

For the second part, you have to invoke the updating of your listbox. Like this:

```
void updateListbox()
{
        if (listbox.Dispatcher.Thread != Thread.CurrentThread)
        {
            //invoke this function, because another thread is calling this function
            listbox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(updateListbox));
        }
        else
        {
            //update listbox
        }
}
```

Comment: i dont get what listbox.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(updateListbox));
does? As for the first part of my question, by current items, i mean the id's presently in the list. Like at every point in the program ,the listbox should reflect the contents of the list.

Comment: your listbox control has a dispatcher, which has an invoke function which makes sure nothing goes wrong if you execute a function from another thread.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is good but BindingList does not have Sort method so i was forced to use list and find out simple solution

In Windows Froms

In cross thread i just used

```
// this = from on which listbox control is created.
this.Invoke(new Action(() => { SomeBindingSource.ResetBindings(false); }));
```

and VOILA

Comment: You could extend the legacy BindingList to support Sorting (or using Dataset, Datatable and Dataview stuff). https://martinwilley.com/net/code/forms/sortablebindinglist.html