# BindingList Cross Thread Error

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a static BindingList in a static class, that both the UI and another class running on a seperate thread add/remove from. This worked fine until I tried to set the BindingList as a datasource for a DataGridView. Now when the other thread attempts to call this method in the static class

```
public static Chunk GetAndRemoveFirstChunk()
{
    Chunk chunk = Chunks.FirstOrDefault();
    Chunks.RemoveAt(0);

    return chunk;
}
```

It gives this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid:
>   Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created
>   on.'

On the line : `Chunks.RemoveAt(0);`

Simply adding `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False;`
to the UI constructor prevents the error but I'm under the impression this is not a good solution.

So what is a good way to solve this?

Comment: What is your application WinForms perhaps?

Comment: The related questions on the sidebar explain why changing your binding list causes changes to the UI which are only allowed on the UI thread. They also contain several suggestions to overcome this. In a nut shell, you need to use Invoke when making changes to the data source.

Comment: @o_weisman I've already looked at all of those but they haven't helped me. How can I call the UI method to invoke the code from a seperate class?

Comment: You can see the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411338/updating-a-listbox-binded-list-in-a-cross-thread-in-c-sharp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating a listbox binded list in a cross-thread in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411338/updating-a-listbox-binded-list-in-a-cross-thread-in-c-sharp)